# Array ConvertAll using Expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, func

Need help on getting this bit of code to work.

```
var splits = rawTokens[startIndex + 2].Value.Split(',');
var paramk = Expression.Parameter(typeof(String), "item");
                    var converter = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(
                        paramk
                        , lToken.CorrespondingType), paramk);

                    var method = typeof(Array).GetMethod("ConvertAll").MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(string), lToken.CorrespondingType });
                    var arrayBuilder = Expression.Call(method, Expression.Constant(splits), converter);
```

This fails with
System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type 'System.Func`2[System.String,System.String]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Converter`2[System.String,System.String]' of method 'System.String[] ConvertAll[String,String](System.String[], System.Converter`2[System.String,System.String])''

Comment: Try passing `typeof(Converter<string,string>)` to `Expression.Lambda()`.  It goes in front of the other parameters.  Well, you really need to get `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` and then `MakeGenericType()` passing `typeof(string)` and `lToken.CorrespondingType`.

Comment: You might also want to check for the special case that `lToken.CorrespondingType == typeof(string)` because then you don't need a conversion.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you. I had tried the first approach already and got Coercion errors. I will need that conversion for sure. Thinking of ditching Expressions for this one but then this is a part of the expression based framework.

Comment: In case the error message wasn't clear, the expression lambda guessed it should make a `Func<string, string>` by looking at the parameter and return types, but `Array.ConvertAll` needed a `Converter<string, string>`.  You'll have to stop it from guessing, by telling it you want a `Converter<string, ?>` where `?` is filled in using `lToken.CorrespondingType`.

Comment: Type converterType = typeof(Converter<,>);
                    Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(string), lToken.CorrespondingType };
                    Type closedConverterType = converterType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

                    var converter = Expression.Lambda(
                        Expression.Convert(Expression.Convert(
                        paramk
                        , lToken.CorrespondingType), closedConverterType),
                        paramk);

Comment: - System.InvalidOperationException: 'No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.String' and 'System.Converter`2[System.String,System.String]'.'